# Каким образом можно отправить запись в базу данных Mysql на Java?

Tags: java, android

Нужно отправить данные с андроид приложения и поместить их в БД сайта. Каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: эм........  а что Вы использовали?

Comment: Пишите php скрипт, принимающий нужные параметры в виде строк и помещающий их в БД чрез PDO. Из приложения отправляйте запрос к этому скрипту с нужными параметрами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда-то разрабатывал приложение, которое отправляло данные из телефона на сервер, а там уже обрабатывалось. У нас была такая реализация:

1. Телефон собирает нужные сведения и формирует JSON объект для отправки.
2. Отправляем POST запрос на сервер, где его обрабатывает PHP скрипт.

Использовал этот 
[пример.](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2013/02/json.html)